# Div filled with image & Div for text

Tags: html, css

How do I fix the image and text divs?

I am trying to make a rack card for a group.

When done, I will be printing the card. It does not need any flexibility, everything is fixed.

I have a container, class="sponsee", with two divs within. One for an image and one for some text.

The container is 270.2px wide and 106.7px high. The image div is 106.7px x 106.7px. The text div is 163.5px x 106.7px.

I am trying to put an image into the image div. I am trying to put text into the text div.

When I put the image into the image div: one, the image does not load; two, the div seems to be split in half.

When I put the H1 and p into the text div: one, the h1 and p are side-by-side instead of h1 up and p down (I put a br in...); two, the div seems to be split in half.

I have not decided on any of my font information.

What am I doing wrong?

```css
/*
Much Gratitude Eric!
http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ 
v2.0 | 20110126
License: none (public domain)
*/

*,
html,
body,
div,
span,
applet,
object,
iframe,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6,
p,
blockquote,
pre,
a,
abbr,
acronym,
address,
big,
cite,
code,
del,
dfn,
em,
img,
ins,
kbd,
q,
s,
samp,
small,
strike,
strong,
sub,
sup,
tt,
var,
b,
u,
i,
center,
dl,
dt,
dd,
ol,
ul,
li,
fieldset,
form,
label,
legend,
table,
caption,
tbody,
tfoot,
thead,
tr,
th,
td,
article,
aside,
canvas,
details,
embed,
figure,
figcaption,
footer,
header,
hgroup,
menu,
nav,
output,
ruby,
section,
summary,
time,
mark,
audio,
video {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  font: inherit;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}


/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */

article,
aside,
details,
figcaption,
figure,
footer,
header,
hgroup,
menu,
nav,
section {
  display: block;
}

body {
  line-height: 1;
}

ol,
ul {
  list-style: none;
}

blockquote,
q {
  quotes: none;
}

blockquote:before,
blockquote:after,
q:before,
q:after {
  content: '';
  content: none;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}


/*
Much Gratitude Eric!
http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ 
v2.0 | 20110126
License: none (public domain)
*/

html {
  max-width: 816px;
  max-height: 432px;
  background-color: #d7c3ff;
}

body {
  width: 812.4px;
  height: 428.4px;
  margin: 1px;
  border: 1px solid #5a2875;
  background-color: #d7c3ff;
}

h4 {
  font-weight: 400;
}

p {
  font-weight: 200;
}

.sponsees {
  width: 810.8px;
  height: 426.8px;
  border: 1px solid #5a2875;
  background-color: #d7c3ff;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
}

.sponsee {
  border: 1px solid #5a2875;
  background-color: #d7c3ff;
  display: flex;
}

.image {
  width: 106.7px;
  height: 106.7px;
  background-color: grey;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: left;
  object-fit: fill;
}

.text {
  width: 163.5px;
  height: 106.7;
  display: right;
  background-color: #d7c3ff;
  color: #5a2875;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: right;
}

#arya {
  width: 106.7px;
  height: 106.7px;
  /* background-image: url(/images/Arya_Llama.png); */
}
```

```html
<div class="sponsees">

  <div class="sponsee">
    <div class="image"></div>
    <img src="/images/Arya_Llama.png" alt="Arya Llama Image">

    <div class="text"></div>
    <h4>Arya Llama</h4>
    <br>
    <p>Absolutely loves being in water & adores celery</p>
  </div>

  <div class="sponsee">
    <div class="image"></div>
    <div class="text"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="sponsee">
    <div class="image"></div>
    <div class="text"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="sponsee">
    <div class="image"></div>
    <div class="text"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="sponsee">
    <div class="image"></div>
    <div class="text"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="sponsee">
    <div class="image"></div>
    <div class="text"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="sponsee">
    <div class="image"></div>
    <div class="text"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="sponsee">
    <div class="image"></div>
    <div class="text"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="sponsee">
    <div class="image"></div>
    <div class="text"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="sponsee">
    <!-- <div class="image"></div>
            <div class="text"></div> -->
  </div>

  <div class="sponsee">
    <div class="image"></div>
    <div class="text"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="sponsee">
    <!-- <div class="image"></div>
            <div class="text"></div> -->
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Just curious. Why are you using a tool from 2011, when it is 2023 and the modern browsers have improved a lot?

Comment: @fat penguin, Hey! Yeah, I thought " * " represented "all". When I went looking through the interwebs, many sources pointed to that particular css reset. I know others are smarter than me so I trusted it was correct. I am still gimping along my learning path...

Answer (score 0):

This should do it.

For the css i used `*` instead of all the items calles below. It basiclly means all of the below.

`*, html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code, del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp, small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var, b, u, i, center, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend, table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td, article, aside, canvas, details, embed, figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary, time, mark, audio, video`

You made the div's correct you only forgot to add the picture and tekst to the div. I also removed the code: `Display: right` This code forced the tekst to set it next to each other and you wanted it to stand under each other.

```css
/*
Much Gratitude Eric!
http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ 
v2.0 | 20110126
License: none (public domain)
*/

*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  font: inherit;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}


/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */

article,
aside,
details,
figcaption,
figure,
footer,
header,
hgroup,
menu,
nav,
section {
  display: block;
}

body {
  line-height: 1;
}

ol,
ul {
  list-style: none;
}

blockquote,
q {
  quotes: none;
}

blockquote:before,
blockquote:after,
q:before,
q:after {
  content: '';
  content: none;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}


/*
Much Gratitude Eric!
http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ 
v2.0 | 20110126
License: none (public domain)
*/

html {
  max-width: 816px;
  max-height: 432px;
  background-color: #d7c3ff;
}

body {
  width: 812.4px;
  height: 428.4px;
  margin: 1px;
  border: 1px solid #5a2875;
  background-color: #d7c3ff;
}

h4 {
  font-weight: 400;
}

p {
  font-weight: 200;
}

.sponsees {
  width: 810.8px;
  height: 426.8px;
  border: 1px solid #5a2875;
  background-color: #d7c3ff;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
}

.sponsee {
  border: 1px solid #5a2875;
  background-color: #d7c3ff;
  display: flex;
}

.image {
  width: 106.7px;
  height: 106.7px;
  background-color: grey;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: left;
  object-fit: fill;
}

.text {
  width: 163.5px;
  height: 106.7;
  background-color: #d7c3ff;
  color: #5a2875;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: right;
}

.topText {
  width: 163.5px;
  height: 26.7px;
}

.bottomText {
  width: 163.5px;
  height: 100px;
}

#arya {
  width: 106.7px;
  height: 106.7px;
  /* background-image: url(/images/Arya_Llama.png); */
}
```

```html
<div class="sponsees">

  <div class="sponsee">
    <div class="image">
     <img src="/images/Arya_Llama.png" alt="Arya Llama Image">
    </div>
    

    <div class="text">
      <div class="topText"> 
        <h4 class= >Arya Llama</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="bottomText">
        <p>Absolutely loves being in water & adores celery</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    
  </div>

  <div class="sponsee">
    <div class="image"></div>
    <div class="text"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="sponsee">
    <div class="image"></div>
    <div class="text"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="sponsee">
    <div class="image"></div>
    <div class="text"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="sponsee">
    <div class="image"></div>
    <div class="text"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="sponsee">
    <div class="image"></div>
    <div class="text"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="sponsee">
    <div class="image"></div>
    <div class="text"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="sponsee">
    <div class="image"></div>
    <div class="text"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="sponsee">
    <div class="image"></div>
    <div class="text"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="sponsee">
    <!-- <div class="image"></div>
            <div class="text"></div> -->
  </div>

  <div class="sponsee">
    <div class="image"></div>
    <div class="text"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="sponsee">
    <!-- <div class="image"></div>
            <div class="text"></div> -->
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I saved a copy of what I submitted so that I can compare and learn from the changes you made. I am very grateful to you. Thank you so much for your time and attention!

Comment: Is it possible to follow people on stackoverflow? Is it possible to direct message others?

Comment: Any idea on why the border spacing is coming up as 0.8px instead of 1.0px? I changed the measure from 1px to 0.8px to reflect the actual computed measure. I have no idea why it was changed to 0.8px though. When I made it 2px, it computed to 2px. I thought it was very strange.

Comment: Hey @JohnTaylor Happy to help you out. As far as I know Stack Overflow doesn't have something like direct messages. When I open the website by running the code snippet it and use inspector. It tells me the border is 1px.

Comment: Well shoot... I am very grateful for you and your time. That is so weird, it still shows me 0.8 for the borders. LOL The finished product looks good though, thanks to your help! Now I just have to get it to the sanctuary so they can print it.